# GoRouter Redirection with Firebase Auth

Tags: flutter, firebase-authentication, flutter-go-router

I'm using `go_router` as my navigation package in my Flutter app, and i want to redirect the user based on their authentication state from the `redirect` property in the `GoRouter` class.

```dart
        redirect: (context, state) {
          final user = context.read<AuthBloc>().authRepo.currentUser;

          if (user == null) {
            return '/login';
          } else {
            return '/root';
          }
        },
```

The problem with this solution is that it does not update, it does not redirect until i hot restart.

Answer (score 0):

You need to return `'/root'` only in case if your current location is `'/login'` and null (do not redirect) overwise:

```
redirect: (context, state) {
      final user = context.read<AuthBloc>().authRepo.currentUser;

      if (user == null) {
        return '/login';
      } else if (state.location == '/login') {
        return '/root';
      }
      return null;
    },
```